# typescript function overloading with different arg object signature

Tags: typescript

I have a function that can receive two different object signatures as an argument. How do I type that?

i.e.

```
fn({ a: 'a', c: 'c' })
fn({ b: 2, c: 'c' })
```

however I tried to define the argument types, TS complains a and b do not exist on that type (only c which exists on both is fine)

```
export type IUploadImageArgs =
    | {
            uri: string;
            type: string;
            path: string;
      }
    | {
            path: string;
            file: any;
      };

const uploadImage = async ({ file, path }: IUploadImageArgs) => {

}
// Property 'file' does not exist on type 'IUploadImageArgs'
```

Side note:
This is for a react native + web project, a function that abstracts the uploading of files, in which the web version accepts the file itself, while the native version accepts the local path of the file.

Thanks!

Comment: How about `function fn(args:{a:string, c:string}|{b:number, c:string})` ?

Comment: I tried that, I'm getting the error a/b does not exist on the args (edited question to reflect that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the answers below cover some useful use cases, for my use case seems the only solution is to implement two different functions and call them based on the current platform, instead of having react native manage the file importing for me.

Thanks @joonas and @kaya3 for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Like d2b said, in that simple case you can just have the parameter be a union type: `function fn(obj: { a: string, c: string } | { b: number, c: string })`.

If you have more complicated needs, like different return value for each set of arguments, you can declare the `function` multiple times. There needs to be a single implementation with a body and parameters that can accept any of the alternatives.

```
function fn(obj: { a: string, c: string }): number;
function fn(obj: { b: number, c: string }): string;
function fn(obj: { a: string, c: string } | { b: number, c: string }): number | string {
  // impl
}
```

Comment: I tried that, I'm getting the error a/b does not exist on the args (edited question to reflect that)

Comment: You can't destructure a property on the argument object unless it exists on _every_ member of the union type (in your case, `path` is safe to destructure but `file` is not). You should do `const uploadImage = (args: IUploadImageArgs) => /* ... */` and then conditionally destructure `args` in the function body once you've [narrowed its type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).

Answer (score 0):

One solution which allows you to destructure a union type like this directly (without first testing which branch of the union it is) is to give every branch the same property names, and make the "missing" properties on each branch optional of type `undefined`.

```
type ArgType =
    | {a: string, b: number, c?: undefined}
    | {a: string, b?: undefined, c: string}

function test({a, b}: ArgType): void {
    a //: string
    b //: number | undefined
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwCrmgXgFBW1APlAbwEMAuKAZ2DgEsA7BAGigCMzaBXAW2YjiYGMA-GXa0AJhABmdCGIC+WHPmJlKNek2bCooidNqyBqqnQQKMk0f2DUA9rSjAIlABTFNcsvGSoAlGQA3W2oxQkVsIigAeijjdQRwlmjYqA5uXjwdcSkZMQwFIA)

This also means each of the non-shared properties acts as a discriminant for the union - without doing this, your code would accept an object like `{a: 'foo', b: 23, c: 'bar'}`, and it's not clear what the correct result should be. By discriminating the union in the above way, this mixed object would not be a valid argument.

Note that because Typescript doesn't keep track of relationships between different variables when doing control-flow type narrowing, if you did destructure `{a, b, c}` then a test to see if `b` is undefined would not narrow `c` to be of type `string`, and vice versa. For that, you should write `arg: ArgType` and destructure it after testing which branch of the union it is.